# Utilities library for opentk

Tags: c#, opentk

Is it a substitute for deprecated `OpenTK.Graphics.Glu` from tao framework?
Especially to the need to geometry rendering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OpenTK` is an evolution of `Tao`. And , honestly, I didn't listen about that `glut` becomes depricated. `glut` functions are widely use till now in `OpenGL` world, as contains a wide range of very useful functions and calculations, you may want avoid to do, if you're not a math expert but just a programmer.

By the way, all that stuff present in `glut` can be done also without use of it (at least I didn't find anything that not ), but, as I said before, you have to have *very* good understanding of math that stands behind all that stuff.

Comment: I means a class called `Glu` from namespace `OpenTK.Graphics`. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3):

OpenTK has its own preferred ways of doing geometry rendering and such. You can, of course, still use the Glu class in the OpenTK.Graphics namespace, however, OpenTK would prefer you (I think) to do change this:

```
Glu.Perspective(MathHelper.PiOver4, AspectRatio, 0.1f, 100f);
```

into this:

```
Matrix4 perspectiveMatrix = Matrix4.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(
    MathHelper.PiOver4,
    .1f, 100f);
GL.LoadMatrix(ref perspectiveMatrix);
```

And you can replace the gluLookAt function like this too. Have a look into the Matrix4 struct. It contains a lot of useful stuff.

Comment: Super helpful.  I believe the there is a missing parameter above:  fovy, aspect, zNear, zFar.